# About geometric quantisation and application to real system

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Quantisation is a important step to properly define a quantum system from a classical one. In a nutshell : 
On a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ and an algebra of function $f$ on $M$, one defines an algebra of self adjoint operator $\hat{f}$ on a Hilbert space with the main rule (defined by Dirac in 1925) that the Poisson brackets corresponds to the commutator
$$\widehat{\{f,g\}}=[\hat{f},\hat{g}].$$

The evolution given by the Hamilton equation in the classical system is then given by the Schrodinger equation in the quantum system.
The usual way of quantisation is to set
$x\rightarrow X$ (multiplicative operator), and $p\rightarrow i\nabla_x$ (derivative operator).
and formally extend this to any analytic function $f(x,p)$

However this raises questions:

1- the quantisation is not unique. Example $px^2$ can be quantised as $X^2\nabla_x$ or $\nabla_x X^2$.

2- the quantisation strongly depend on the choice of coordinate.

These are very important issues both for physics and mathematics. Ideally one should be able to construct a quantisation only from a geometrical properties of $(M,\omega)$. This is the aim of geometric quantisation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization. Unfortunattely I am not yet very familiar with this field. So here are my questions.

Let $(M,\omega,H)$ with $H$ an hamiltonian on $M$,

1-Can we define conditions such that the quantisation of $H$ is unique up to an unitary transform (ie whatever the choice of coordinate on $M$)?

2-If the quantisation is not unique, do we still have properties that can be deduced only from the classical system?

3-Can we get some estimate of the spectrum of $\hat{H}$ whatever the quantisation is ?

A good practical example I am interesting in for these questions is the simple harmonic oscilator.

Any partial answer would be great. I would be happy as well with a good reference to geometric quantisation.
Thanks a lot